# Add custom field to ModelSerializer and fill it in post save signal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my API I have a route to add a resource named Video. 
I have a post_save signal to this Model where I proccess this video and I generate a string. I want a custom field in my serializer to be able to fill it with this text that was generated. So, in my response I can have this value.

```py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'description', 'file')

@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def encode_video(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    string_generated = do_stuff()
```

Right now what I am getting in my response is:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "owner": "b424bc3c-5792-470f-bac4-bab92e906b92",
    "description": "",
    "file": "https://z.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/sample.mkv"
}
```

I expect a new key "string" with the value generated by the signal.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append `string_generated` in your response you need to be able to access that field from your serializer. There are 2 convenient ways to do that:

1. Add `string_generated` as a field in your model and add that in `VideoSerializer` as a `SerializerMethodField` so that `string_generated` will be a read-only value. This means it will only appear in response. And finally delete your post signal and override the save() method instead:

```py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    string_generated = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_string_generated')

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'description', 'file')
        read_only_fields = ('string_generated')

    def get_string_generated(self, obj):
        return obj.string_generated
```

```py
# models.py
class Video(models.Model):
    # your fields...
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        string_generated = do_stuff()
        super(Video, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

2. If possible, delete your post-signal. Then, add `do_stuff` as `SerializerMethodField` in your `VideoSerializer`:

```py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    string_generated = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'description', 'file')

    def get_string_generated(self, obj):
        return do_stuff()
```

Comment: When I call `instance.save` method it will trigger the post_save signal again and it keeps in a infinite loop

Comment: The video file is stored in s3, and I use its URL as input in my `post_save` method inside the `do_stuff()` . So I think just override the save method won't work

Comment: Actually, there will be no difference in terms of s3 upload between overriding save() method and adding post signal for your Video model.

Comment: This way I get `The field 'string_generated' was declared on serializer VideoSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option`. So, if I include it in the fields I get `Got a TypeError when calling Video.objects.create(). This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to Video.objects.create(). You may need to make the field read-only, or override the VideoSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.`

Comment: Okay I've edited my post, in case you are using an older version.

Comment: same error, saying that that it's not in the fields. I'm using `djangorestframework==3.9.1` and `Django==2.1.9`

Comment: Two things come to my mind: Are you changing the name of the get_string_generated method? Or have you applied makemigrations & migrate after you have added steing_genrated to your model?

Comment: yes and yes. can't figure out why the problem occurs

Comment: I have added one more line in my answrr, can you try again?

Comment: I've solved by adding `string_generated` in the fields serializer and int the save method I've used *args and **kwargs as parameters. `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes but it string_generated is not read-only anymore. Just to let you know :)